# Android Studio Text not conforming to layout_margin when I run App on Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to resolve a Layout Margin issue, where after I run the app on the emulator the Status Text doesn't appear where I intend it to be.
Attached is the full layout code. How can I improve the code to mitigate this issue in the future?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/settings_profile_image"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/default_profile" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settings_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
    android:text="@string/user_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settings_user_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
    android:text="@string/user_profile_status"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: add your complete layout file code

Comment: `android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"` will place the view 260 DP from bottom. Your emulator has larger screen than the preview, therefore 260 take smaller size. If you want the view to align to bottom of other view, then you should not align it to the layout's bottom, but alig it to the bottom of t=other view

Comment: Full *layout* code will be good. And it seems hardcoded *margins* causing the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 1st place, you may want to try the constraint layout introduced by android as part of android material design which is aimed at avoiding all the overhead of nesting views. In constraint layout views can be dragged and drooped and they can be assigned margins in the multiples of 8. It is highly suggested to use constraint layouts as opposed to the old nesting of layouts.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the status below user name, just use

```
android:layout_below="@+id/settings_username"
```

In your current layout, marginTop is useless, vertical position is decided by

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
```

It is better to use ContraintLayout, which will remove all unused attributes (e.g, if margin is useless, margin attribute is automatically removed).

Answer (score 0):

Try this You just have to remove  **android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"** and **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** and Add **android:layout_below="@+id/settings_username"** in settings_user_status

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/settings_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_profile" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:text="@string/user_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_user_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_username"
        android:text="@string/user_profile_status"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```